# I need to set disable or enable in the field in the checkbox using useformik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik

I need to set like if the check box is not selected then date field stay in disabling if check box selected mean **true** date appear date field is getting disable but when I check on the check box that disables and also i checking true and false condition enables functionality not working I am not sure what I missed need to set this invalidation in proper validation I am using useFormik

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  list: Yup.array().of(Yup.string()).min(1, "Required!").required("Required!"),
  isCheck: Yup.boolean(),
  startDate: Yup.string().when("isCheck", {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
    otherwise: Yup.boolean,
  }),
  isCheck: Yup.boolean(),
  endDate: Yup.string().when("isCheck", {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
    otherwise: Yup.boolean,
  }),
});
```

```
const ruleForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      // Status: "que",
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      deltaChange(values);
    },
  });
```

```
           <Box className={classes.formText}>
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={ruleForm.values.isCheck}
                      onChange={ruleForm.handleChange}
                      color="primary"
                      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                    />
                    <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
                      <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold"> By Update Date : </Box>
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                  <Grid container display="flex" spacing={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <TextField
                        id="outlined-select-currency"
                        label="Start Date"
                        variant="outlined"
                        disabled={!ruleForm.values.isCheck}
                        size="small"
                        type="date"
                        InputLabelProps={{
                          shrink: true,
                        }}
                        onChange={ruleForm.handleChange}
                        value={ruleForm.values.startDate}
                        error={ruleForm.errors.startDate}
                        helperText={ruleForm.errors.startDate}
                        name="startDate"
                      ></TextField>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <TextField
                        id="outlined-select-currency"
                        label="End Date"
                        variant="outlined"
                        size="small"
                        // onChange={(e) => setDate(e)}
                        type="date"
                        disabled={!ruleForm.values.isCheck}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                          shrink: true,
                        }}
                        onChange={ruleForm.handleChange}
                        value={ruleForm.values.endDate}
                        error={ruleForm.errors.endDate}
                        helperText={ruleForm.errors.endDate}
                        name="endDate"
                      ></TextField>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
```

[image: seeimage]

Comment: What is your initialValues ?

Comment: for now nothing in initialValues

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  list: Yup.array().of(Yup.string()).min(1, "Required!").required("Required!"),
  isCheck: Yup.boolean(),
 startDate: Yup.string().when('isCheck', {
    is: (isCheck: boolean) => isCheck === true,
    then: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
  }),
  endDate: Yup.string().when("isCheck", {
     is: (isCheck: boolean) => isCheck === true,
    then: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
  }),
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).